# Receiving broadcast in apps in stopped state

Tags: android

The keyword here is Hyuawei, because on this device (ALE-L21@Android5.0.1) I get

```
06-13 14:28:06.470 3198-3746/? I/ActivityManager: FireWall skip stopped pkg: com.my.package for broadcast!
```

The way I'm sending broadcast:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("SOME_ACTION_NAME");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Of course receiver is exported in manifest and works on other devices like Samsung.

Did anyone encountered workarounded this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that your app is in the stopped state, either because it was installed but the user never launched an activity, or the user clicked the "force stop" button in Settings, or the device uses "force stop" elsewhere (e.g., swiping off the overview screen).

AFAIK, `FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES` does not affect this. Besides, [implicit broadcasts, such as yours, are banned on Android 8.0+](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/04/11/android-o-implicit-broadcast-ban.html).

Use an explicit `Intent` (i.e., where you set the `ComponentName`), instead of an implicit one, to address both problems.

Comment: Thank you for the article, interesting workaround. My case is that I'm broadcasting kind of HELLO to the system, so I need to workaround this limitation somehow. (need to try workaround first, but I'd prefer some "legal" solution)